# How to configure Eclipse's "clean" to remove unused imports?

Tags: java, eclipse

Due to a massive refactoring, i ended up having a lot of unused imports across many files. Using Eclipse, is there a way to remove them all?

Comment: Can't you select a package and do `Organize Imports`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is no one shot solution through cleanup.

```
1) right click on package then Source->Organize Imports
2)`Ctrl+Shift+O` .
```

Here is [Save Actions](http://eclipseone.wordpress.com/2009/12/13/automatically-format-and-cleanup-code-every-time-you-save/) another way which can even avoid `Ctrl+Shift+O`

Answer (score 4):

Select all your projects and then hit `Ctrl+Shift+O`.  It's also available at Source -> Organize Imports if you right click on the selected projects.

Answer (score 1):

You can right-click on source folder in the project and select Source > Organize Imports.  This will organize the imports for (recursively) all source files contained in that source folder.  This can also be done on individual packages.

As for tying the "Organize Imports" action to a "Clean", that will be trickier.  I think the closest thing would be to attach an Ant build.xml to the "Clean" stage for the project.  You could set up the build.xml to invoke Jalopy, which can organize imports.  I don't recommend this approach, as it modifies files behind Eclipse's back, which can cause frustrating issues.

As a compromise, you could go to Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Save Actions >
[x] Perform the selected actions on save 
[x] Organize imports

Answer (score 0):

Right click the package then select `Source->Organize Imports`.

Answer (score 0):

Visit http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-eclipse-clean/ .

Detailed HOW TO work with profiles and clean up your code.

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple Genius!

Import packages :  **Ctrl + Shift + O** and

Remove Unused packages : **Ctrl + Shift + O**